# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples:

Tags: python, csv

i want to calculate linear regression with the code below;
But i have an error on line "predicted = cross_val_predict(lr, x, y, cv=10)"
note;all imports are okay

> Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 4538]

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'...movie_metadata.csv')
x = df.budget.tolist()
y = df.imdb_score.tolist()

lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()



predicted = cross_val_predict(lr, x, y, cv=10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(y, predicted)
ax.plot([y.min(), y.max()], [y.min(), y.max()], 'k--', lw=4)
ax.set_xlabel('Measured')
ax.set_ylabel('Predicted')
plt.show()
```